# How to remove 'SOH' characters injected in rest service?

Tags: java

Sending large json as payload to spring boot rest service. Accepting this json as String as **publish(@RequestBody String inputJson)**. when I receive this json payload as string in my service characters like 'SOH' are injected. These characters(SOH) are repeated after specific number of characters in string. Why these characters are injected? How to remove these characters in service?

Comment: Can you provide some example that we can test out?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.